# help me to identify what is this electronic component for a Samsung oven

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics, identification, components

DK00117C 2050T[image]

I want to repair a Samsung Chief 600-power supply but I can't identify this component.

Missing 12 volt on the stabilizer

Comment: Looks to be a transformer.

Comment: Do you have a reason to suspect the transformer? SMPS transformers seldom fail.

Comment: Transformer or common mode choke. Picture of back side?

Comment: IC 101 looks like it’s missing the top.

Comment: It is a SPMS transformer. Likely a custom part you cannot buy anywhere. But likely that is not broken, the likely reason is something else than the transformer is broken.

Comment: IC 101 is intact. Was only dirty. I have 160DC input  for SPMS and 0 V output. 
I have put 16V DC input for regulator 7812A and output is 12v

Comment: I’d be suspecting the little brown electro. You marked it ‘ok’ - how did you test it? An ESR meter is required. If in doubt, replace it as it is only worth a few cents.

Answer (score 1):

That's the transformer of a switched-mode power-supply (SMPS).

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [Tutorials Point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/electronic_circuits/electronic_circuits_smps.htm).*

It's the power-transformer of the diagram. It is switched at high frequency so the magnetic component can be much smaller than a mains frequency transformer.

There will be a DC voltage of about √2 times your mains voltage on this circuit. You have been warned.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bespoke flyback transformer and, any further details about it will be known only to the designer and the supplier of that component. Without knowing either you are stuck (in case you are trying to reverse engineer it). If you know the designer and it isn't IP then you might be able to get details from them.

However, it's probably quicker to design a new transformer based on the flyback controller (possibly IC101) used on the circuit board and the likely tools they'll provide on their site. However, you will need to know or estimate the AC input voltage range and the maximum DC current drawn from this power supply and the DC output voltage(s).

Because you didn't recognize the component it's likely that you won't have acquired the necessary skills to properly dismantle it in order to recreate it. This route can be problematic because it's easy to miss subtleties and the ferrite parts will generally be unmarked.